# How to change speed rotation of angular Material progress-spinner

Tags: angular, web, angular-material, spinner

I use material progress-spinner in my web-project, and it rotate very slowly for.
Does anyone know to increase rotation speed of this spinner?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation change of the speed is not supported.

You can use `::ng-deep` to overwrite css and put your own speed or you can create your own spinner and have full control over it.